How to write an abstraction in Rust with multiple implementations
In my application I want to have an EventPersister trait that defines an abstraction of persisting events, then have various implementations that, for example, persist events in memory, in the file system, or in a database.
This is a cut-down version of my EventPersister trait:
pub trait Keyed {
    fn type_name(self: &Self) -> &'static str;
    fn key(self: &Self) -> String;
}

pub trait EventPersister {
    fn log<T>(self: &mut Self, event: &T) -> Result<(), ()>
    where T: Keyed + Serialize;
}

I have an implementation of this that persists events in memory:
pub struct LogEntry;

pub struct InMemoryEventPersister {
    entries: Vec<LogEntry>,
}

impl InMemoryEventPersister {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            entries: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}

impl EventPersister for InMemoryEventPersister {
    fn log<T>(self: &mut Self, event: &T) -> Result<(), ()>
    where T: Keyed + Serialize
{
  --snip-
}


So far so good, but now I am stuck trying to write a function that will return a concrete implementation of the EventPersister trait depending on how the application is configured. For simplicity, the code below always returns the in-memory persister. Note that this code will not compile:
pub fn build_event_persister() -> &'static dyn EventPersister {
    &InMemoryEventPersister::new()
}

I tried many variations of this syntax, read all the docs and SO articles I can find, but nothing is pointing me in the right direction.
Creating an abstraction around some functionality with multiple implementation options is something I do a lot in other languages, where typically you define multiple classes that implement an interface. I'm finding it hard to believe that Rust doesn't support this very common pattern.
-- EDIT -- Nov 24, 2024
For further clarification of what I want to do, here is the full source code for the in-memory version. I combined all of my source files into one file here to make it more readable, adding mod{} sections to help the reader. This might have messed up some of the type references. In my application (with modules in separate source files) this code did compile and run without errors.
pub type Timestamp = u128;

pub struct LogEntry {
    pub timestamp: Timestamp,
    pub type_name: String,
    pub key: String,
    pub serialization: Option<Vec<u8>>,
}

pub struct EventQueryOptions {
    pub include_serialization: bool,
}

type EventQueryResult = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = LogEntry>>;

pub trait Keyed {
    fn type_name(self: &Self) -> &'static str;
    fn key(self: &Self) -> String;
}

pub trait EventPersister {
    fn log<T>(self: &mut Self, event: &T, timestamp: &Timestamp) -> Result<(), ()>
    where
        T: Keyed + Serialize;

    fn query_by_timestamp<'a>(
        self: &'a Self,
        start: &Timestamp,
        end: &Timestamp,
        options: &EventQueryOptions,
    ) -> EventQueryResult;

    fn query_by_key_prefix<'a>(
        self: &'a Self,
        key_prefix: &str,
        options: &EventQueryOptions,
    ) -> EventQueryResult;
}

mod in_memory {
    pub struct InMemoryEventPersister {
        entries: Vec<LogEntry>,
    }

    struct LogEntryIterator<'a, F> where F: Fn(&'a LogEntry) -> bool {
        entries: &'a Vec<LogEntry>,
        index: usize,
        filter: F,
    }

    impl InMemoryEventPersister {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Self {
                entries: Vec::new(),
            }
        }
    }

    impl<'a, F> LogEntryIterator<'a, F> where F: Fn(&'a LogEntry) -> bool {
        pub fn new(entries: &'a Vec<LogEntry>, filter: F) -> Self {
            Self {
                entries,
                filter,
                index: entries.len(),
            }
        }
    }

    impl<'a, F> Iterator for LogEntryIterator<'a, F>  where F: Fn(&'a LogEntry) -> bool {
        type Item = LogEntry;

        fn next(self: &mut Self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
            loop {
                self.index = self.index - 1;
                match self.entries.get(self.index) {
                    Some(entry) if (self.filter)(entry) => return Some(LogEntry {
                        key: entry.key.clone(),
                        timestamp: entry.timestamp.clone(),
                        type_name: entry.type_name.clone(),
                        serialization: entry.serialization.clone()
                    }),
                    Some(_) => continue,
                    None => return None,
                }
            }
        }
    }

    impl super::EventPersister for InMemoryEventPersister {
        fn log<T>(self: &mut Self, event: &T, timestamp: &data_types::Timestamp) -> Result<(), ()>
        where
            T: Keyed + Serialize
        {
            let mut buffer = Vec::new();
            let mut serializer = Serializer::new(&mut buffer);
            event.serialize(&mut serializer).unwrap();

            let log_entry = LogEntry {
                timestamp: timestamp.clone(),
                type_name: event.type_name().to_owned(),
                key: event.key(),
                serialization: Some(buffer),
            };

            self.entries.push(log_entry);
            Result::Ok(())
        }

        fn query_by_timestamp(
            self: &Self,
            start: &data_types::Timestamp,
            end: &data_types::Timestamp,
            _options: &EventQueryOptions,
        ) -> EventQueryResult {
            let iter = LogEntryIterator::new(
                &self.entries, 
                move|entry|entry.timestamp >= *start && entry.timestamp < *end);
            Box::new(iter);
        }

        fn query_by_key_prefix(
            self: &Self,
            key_prefix: &str,
            _options: &EventQueryOptions,
        ) -> EventQueryResult {
            let iter = LogEntryIterator::new(
                &self.entries,
                move|entry|entry.key.starts_with(key_prefix));
            Box::new(iter)
        }
    }
}

mod events {
    #[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
    pub struct Ack {
        pub message_ref: MessageRef,
        pub subscription_id: SubscriptionId,
        pub consumer_id: ConsumerId,
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
    pub struct Nack {
        pub message_ref: MessageRef,
        pub subscription_id: SubscriptionId,
        pub consumer_id: ConsumerId,
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
    pub struct Publish {
        pub message_ref: MessageRef,
    }

    impl super::Keyed for Ack {
        fn type_name(self: &Self) -> &'static str {
            "Ack"
        }
        fn key(self: &Self) -> String {
            self.message_ref.to_key()
        }
    }

    impl super::Keyed for Nack {
        fn type_name(self: &Self) -> &'static str {
            "Nack"
        }
        fn key(self: &Self) -> String {
            self.message_ref.to_key()
        }
    }

    impl super::Keyed for Publish {
        fn type_name(self: &Self) -> &'static str {
            "Publish"
        }
        fn key(self: &Self) -> String {
            self.message_ref.to_key()
        }
    }
}


Why &'static dyn EventPersister and not Box<dyn EventPersister>? This is exactly what other languages do. See this documentation about trait objects.

In that case, the compiler says "the trait EventPersister cannot be made into an object".
I got &'static dyn EventPersister from a compiler generated suggestion, but it doesn't work.

What is Serializer? Do you expect to serialize to that same format in other EventPersister implementations, or do you plan to use different formats in different persisters?

use rmp_serde::Serializer;
I might use different serializers for in-memory vs file system vs database, but for sure the serialize/deserialize have to match for a particular implementation of EventPersister.
I haven't really figured out the deserialization of log entries yet.

Note that you can use the rmp_serde::to_vec(&value) utility to serialize the value without constructing a Serializer. Also, you can use &self and &mut self in function declarations instead of self: &Self and self: &mut Self respectively. The former is both shorter and more idiomatic.

In situations like these I always end up using an enum. If your application/library has a single (or a small number of) entry point, you don't even need to use an enum - if you make all code using an EventPersister generic over the EventPersister type, you can simply specify the type at the top level entry point invocation. For example, in a CLI app: if args.in_memory { App::run(InMemoryEventPersister::new()) } else { App::run(FilePersister::new()) }. In fact, I followed the latter approach for a very similar system in an app I am currently implementing.

You will almost certainly need to adjust some aspects of the design to support deserialization - an open-ended T won't cut it there because you'll need to identify the concrete type which to deserialize. That adjustment might simplify log() as well.

Doing what you set out to do is quite difficult in current Rust, because trait objects are largely incompatible with generic methods. The best way to do it is to give up on trait object and make EventPersister an enum:
enum EventPersister {
    InMemory(InMemoryEventPersister),
    File(FileEventPersister),
    // ...
}

impl EventPersister {
    pub fn log<T: Keyed + Serialize>(&mut self, event: &T) -> Result<(), ()> {
        match self {
            InMemory(p) => p.log(event),
            File(p) => p.log(event),
        }
    }
}

At this point you don't e
need an EventPersister trait, though you could certainly have one if you find it useful. (In that case, look into the enum_dispatch crate which eliminates some of the boilerplate.) Functions like build_event_persister() would just return the EventPersister enum.
If you really insist on dynamic dispatch, it's possible, but quite hard in general, and exceedingly hard in your case. The general technique to do it is described by David Tolnay as part of erased-serde, and is reasonably simple to apply to your EventPersister and Keyed crates without serialization. What makes your trait hard is that the generic method EventPersister::log() depends on another object-unsafe trait, Serialize. It should be possible to make use of erased-serde, but doing so in practice runs into several problems that are beyond the scope of this answer - I could only make it work by forking erased-serde and modifying the definition of the EventPersister trait, so that's not an approach worth pursuing.

After reading the answer from @prog-fh, I was thinking of having a struct wrap the implementations of EventPersister with match statements to select the configured implementation, but your solution is even better. I didn't realize that you can add methods to enum - I only started learning Rust a few days ago.

@bikeman868 My implementation only removes the unnecessary wrapping (as it defines the methods on the enum), but the match is still there. Have fun with Rust - its approach to building abstractions takes a bit of getting used to, but after a while you'll find it quite natural. In particular, it's sometimes not immediately obvious which problem is hard and which is easy. I got nerd-sniped into trying to get the "boxed" solution to worked, and failed.

@bikeman868 If you describe what you actually want your log() implementations to do, we might be able to suggest an even simpler solution which would actually work with trait objects. This way we're likely solving the y in this xy problem. That's not always a bad thing, solving the y can be a learning experience for both the asker and the answerer, but it's probably suboptimal for the final product.

I will edit my question and add my implementation of the in-memory version to provide more context.

I refactored all of my code to make EventPersister an enum rather than a trait and it all worked out well. The code compiles and runs without errors and without exposing the in-memory implementation. I will wait a bit to see if any other answers are forthcoming before marking this as the correct answer

@bikeman868 Given your requirements, an enum is almost certainly the way to go. The only downside of the enum is that it becomes impossible to add a new kind of EventPersister by some downstream code. If the crate that defines it were a library, and a user of that library needed its own kind of EventPersister, it couldn't add one without modifying the library crate.

Thanks for pointing this out. In my case this is an application, not a library (at this point) so this should not be an issue.

The problem comes from the log() method depending on a generic parameter.
When a trait is implemented in order to achieve dynamic polymorphism, (you can call this trait an interface) each implementer must provide an implementation of the expected function with the exact same prototype.
However, using a generic can be seen as defining exactly the prototype only at the call site (with actual types chosen); such a prototype cannot have been determined beforehand by the implementers in order to prepare the virtual-tables.
See the reference about object-safety.
If your approach strongly relies on dynamic polymorphism (OO), then you should probably also consider the event parameter of log() the same way: event: &dyn Keyed.
Then, you would be able to return a Box<dyn EventPersister>.
You will face the same problem about Serialize since this trait (from serde, I assume) is not object-safe for the same reason (generic parameters).
Maybe should you introduce a serialize() method in Keyed and rely internally on serde::Serialize in the implementers?

I think I need to reset my expectations of Rust. I thought is would be like C# or Java, but with explicit lifetimes rather than garbage collection. Now I am thinking it's more like C with lifetimes derived from static analysis rather than malloc and free.

This is day 3 of my Rust journey. Maybe you can help out by using your experience to suggest the best way of solving this problem in Rust.
I need to abstract some functionality (which needs generics) and want to be able to choose different implementations of that abstraction.

@bikeman868 From your question (especially the usage of dyn, the term interface...) I thought you considered dynamic polymorphism as mandatory in the design of your code. Of course, if you can switch to using an enum, as suggested in another answer, this would probably help (I cannot tell, since I don't know the exact nature of your problem).

I added a more complete source listing in the question to provide more context on what I want to do.
